# Limit the number of entries to a core data application with the use of in app purchases

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, in-app-purchase

I have an app in the App Store that is currently chargeable to users, where the user can create an unlimited amount of entries to keep track of minor transactions.

I want to change the model to be free to use, but with a limit, and in-app purchase to unlock an unlimited amount of entries. This will give the user the ability to try the app. This is an iOS 8 and iOS 7 iPhone app.

Please forgive my ignorance on the IAP side of things and with this aspect of data limitations.

I have the code working for IAPs by following this example here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_in_app_purchase.htm . I see my iTunes Connect entry for the IAP and through a test account, it allows me to purchase, but it's not actually unlocking anything (as mentioned, this is my first adventure into IAPs).

With this in mind, I'm sorry for the basic question, but are there are any guides available for this aspect of limiting the number of entries allowed in the Core Data aspect of the app, to later be unlocked to a limited amount by the IAP?

Ideally, I'd like to have two IAPs: 1) Unlock 250 entries for price one, and 2) Unlock unlimited entries for price two.

So, my main question is:

How can I limit the number of entries in my app to x amount, which is then increased to unlimited when the IAP goes through?

Any guidance on this would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no built-in way to tell Core Data: "don't create more than 250 instances of this entity".

However, before the user starts creating an entry, you can check how many entries have *already* been created. You can do that using `NSFetchRequest`. Let's assume that your Core Data entity is named `Entry`:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entry"];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = ... // get the context somehow
NSUInteger currentCount = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:error];
NSUInteger entriesLimit = 250; //or whatever you want
BOOL isPurchaseActive = ...// check whether an appropriate in-app purchase is active
if(currentCount >= entriesLimit && !isPurchaseActive) {
  //Notify the user: sorry, you have reached the limit of entries. Wanna buy more?
}
```

Comment: Dear Michal - thank you so much for the response and this makes sense. That's really helpful and I see that I can use this code to actually determine the number of entries and go from there. Thanks again - I appreciate it!